# Port subviews of UIView to UIScrollView without breaking constraints?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

There's a view that currently has a static view that I would like to be able to scroll, because certain elements are blocked by the keyboard in 4-inch phones. However, I find that if I simply copy all of the existing subviews to be nested under a `UIScrollView`, the constraints are broken. I would prefer not to have to methodically set up each subview. Is there any way to convert a plain `UIView` to a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Why not just put that container view into UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xib to create a new UIView which nested with your existing subviews, after that，you can add constraints on it as your wish .

Then useing code to add this container view to the scrollview.

I think this method should be worked.